# Update data from Dynamic Table created in C# from Sql Table Using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have Dynamic Table created from Excel using Code

```
DataTable dt = ExcelToTable(path);
```

DataTable dt has columns with Name:

1.Updated_Supplier_Remark

2.Updated_Date

Another table is SQL Table tblExportOrderdatas with Columns:

1.Supplier_Remark

2.Date

I want to update data from one to other like:

- Supplier_Remark with Updated_Supplier_Remark
- Date with Updated_Date

How can I update data from dt to tblExportOrderdatas using LINQ only?
I am able to do it Using SQL Query but need to do it by Linq only
I think I am solving this with the wrong approach. Please guide/suggest 
    Below code is not saving data. Please suggest.

```
int sid = Convert.ToInt32(sExportID);

var objtblInbox = (from m in objLCSEntities.tblExportOrderdatas where m.Batch_ID == sid select m).ToList<tblExportOrderdata>();

foreach (var p in objtblInbox)
{
    var nflplayer = new tblExportOrderdata();
    foreach (DataRow dr in copydt.Rows) // search whole table
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dr["Updated_Supplier_Remarks"].ToString())) // if not empty
        {
            nflplayer.Supplier_Remark = dr["Updated_Supplier_Remarks"].ToString();
        }
        objLCSEntities.tblExportOrderdatas.AddObject(nflplayer);
    }
}
objLCSEntities.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: linq is a query that reads, not writes.  Is the code you posted what you are calling "Sql Query"?

Comment: i am able to do it Using Sql Procedure but now want to do it Using Linq

Comment: @jdweng as per my code and your statement i am using the wrong approach can you guide me the right one

Comment: You need a foreach loop and then inside the loop you need to change the values.  You can't do it stickly with linq without replacing the entire table.

Comment: @jdweng i am new to linq can you please suggest what i can do to fulfill my requirement